# KieBuilder and KieBase

Tags: java, drools

knowledge builder has a method called addResources. Does KieBuilder have a similar one. Can anyone tell me how to add multiple resources to a KieBase in drools 6.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KieBuilder dont have similar API's as KieBase.If you want to use KieBuilder then you can try with below approach.

```
file = new File("/home/abhumbe/Sample.drl");
resource = kieServices.getResources().newFileSystemResource(file).setResourceType(ResourceType.DRL);
kfs.write(resource);

file = new File("/home/abhumbe/Sample2.drl");
resource = kieServices.getResources().newFileSystemResource(file).setResourceType(ResourceType.DRL);
kfs.write(resource);


KieBuilder kb = kieServices.newKieBuilder(kfs);
kb.buildAll();
```

Comment: Thanks, So i should add all the resources to a single file system and use build all.. Is there any possibility to check for errors in KieBuilder when each and every resource is added?

Comment: I could see that the Rules are getting overwritten and the last written rule only is there in the KieFileSystem.. Can I add the resource as a list in KieFileSystem?

Comment: atm i am not sure if we can add resources as list, but it worth to give a try

Comment: Adding as a list is not possible and the problem I had is with the path.. When is set different source and target path then it worked..